# Finding why there is no solution or why there is only one

Tags: calculus

The given function is $$ f(x) = \frac{x^2 -5x+4}{x-3} $$

Part A of the question where the domain is $(3, \infty)$  $f(x)$ = inverse function of $x$ has no real solution ( according to the book) however the function and its inverse actually do intersect once.

meanwhile part b the domain is $(-\infty,3)$ and the function of its inverse intersect twice when plotted but according to the book there is only one solution.

Am I wrong tp think that there is a huge error in these questions or am I interpreting the question wrong?

Comment: Did you consider that the $x$-values of the intersection points have to be in the domain ? It would be helpful, if you would mention the approximate positions of the intersections.

Comment: Not sure whether this idea is correct, but don't we just need the fix-points of $f(x)$ ? In this case, the only solution would be $x=2$, approving the result in the book.

Answer (score 3):

You have to look at the inverse in the domain where they are defined.

For $x>3$ the inverse is $g(x)=\dfrac{1}{2} \left(\sqrt{x^2-2 x+9}+x+5\right)$

And $f(x) = \dfrac{x^2 -5x+4}{x-3}$ intersects $g(x)$ at $x=4 - \sqrt 2\approx 2.59<3$

So they don't intersect.

For $x<3$ the inverse is $h(x)=\dfrac{1}{2} \left(x+5-\sqrt{x^2-2 x+9}\right)$

which intersects $f(x)$ at $x=2$. The other intersection is $x=4+\sqrt 2\approx 5.41>3$

Thus they intersect only once.

Hope this helps